# Sharepoint 2013 with SQL Authentication

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service, sql

I'm trying to get Sharepoint 2013 to install correctly with SQL Authentication. The domain environment I am running this under, service accounts are not easy to come by and have to be renewed every year. Down the road, I don't want Sharepoint to go down because the account expired. Both the Sharepoint Server and the SQL Server are on the domain, and users can log into each server. The issue that I am encountering is that some part of Sharepoint is trying to authenticate with the farm account; which does not access to the Database due to it being a local account. The errors are below.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

Error on the SQL Server (in the Event Viewer)

```
Account For Which Logon Failed:
Security ID:        NULL SID
Account Name:       SPFarm
Account Domain:     SPMain
```

I am initially setting up the farm using the following command. Once the databases are created, I run the Configuration Wizard and complete it. I am able to log into the Central Administration and start the Farm Configuration Wizard. After the first step, the User Profile Service fails to start with the "User cannot be found" error.

```
$dbcredential = New-Object –typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –argumentlist “Sharepoint”, (ConvertTo-secureString “PASSWORD” –AsPlainText –Force)
$fmcredential = New-Object –typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –argumentlist “SPFarm”, (ConvertTo-secureString “PASSWORD” –AsPlainText –Force)

New-SPConfigurationDatabase –DatabaseName “Sharepoint_Config” –DatabaseServer “RSVSRV07-DB03” –Passphrase (ConvertTo-SecureString “PASSWORD” –AsPlaintext –Force) –FarmCredentials $dbcredential –DatabaseCredentials $dbcredential
```

I am out of ideas on how to get this working. I cannot find a guide on how to do this, so I might be missing a step, but I don't know what I could be missing. I have the March 2013 update installed.